# Function work timer

Tags: c++, sockets, function, timer

I have a function which receives data from socket, i need to stop function when 5 second passed without creating additional thread. My code:

```
void TestReceive()
{
 //how to stop code below when 5 second passed&
 size_t received = 0;
 while (received < 4)
 {
  ssize_t r = read(fd, buffer, 4);
  if (r <= 0) break;
  received += r;
 }
}
```

Comment: Without creating additional function... what can you modify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use select(), this will block until something is available to read or at most for the time specified in the timeval as below.

```
int select(int nfds, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds, fd_set *exceptfds, struct timeval *timeout);
```

select() does not read or write, what it does is for a set of descriptors (readfds, writefds, and/or exceptfds), it will wait/block until one of the following happens:

- there is a descriptor ready to be read from
- there is a descriptor ready to be written to
- there is an exception on one of the descriptors, like it was closed
- if the timeout is specified, when the configured time expires

If you just simply need to "wait" (sleep) for 5 seconds, then read, you could sleep (`usleep()` on linux) for 5 seconds, then do a non-blocking read either by setting the socket options, or call select() with the minimum timeout and check if there is anything to be read.

Here's a related question. [How C++ select() function works in Unix OSs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838112/how-c-select-function-works-in-unix-oss)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I readed article you gave me, but i didn't understand - will `select` read? I need to read in 5 seconds, problem in my code that read can block thread more than 5 seconds. Can you please give me some example?

Comment: @Becker, ok, I didnt understand that you had to wait 5 seconds, then read. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As @Brady suggested, select() will work

You can also set a socket option 
`setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO ...`

Answer (score 0):

Record the current time before the loop starts.
On each iteration - check if 5 seconds have passed - if yes - **break;**

Comment: Uff, this isnt very nice to the rest of the processes on the machine.

Comment: @Brady - Ok, I see your point looking at your answer. But using select still doesn't guarantee that the whole loop will end in 5 seconds - what if each 'read'/select finishes in 4 seconds? you still have to record the time before you start listening and compare on each iteration.

Comment: @Bond, ya I guess we need more context, Im not sure why he has the loop. Maybe a 1 second select() 5 times would work and would impact the rest of the processes much less. The select() will sleep the amount of time specified or less, so some extra logic will be needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following approach:

- measure the current time into a var say startTime;
- LOOP
- read from your socket USING a timeout (select). Let the timeout to be **startTime + 5 sec - now**
- iterate until the timeout has matched (or timeout is to little to apply)

This approach uses the time out instead of an separate thread